# dots inside circle with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to make multiple dots inside circle, and I did with for loop

```
var svg = d3
    .select('.container')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h);    

var group = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(500,200)');

for ( let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {

    var rad = Math.sqrt(~~(Math.random() * 100 * 100)),
        angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
        posx = Math.cos(angle),
        posy = Math.sin(angle);

    var c2 = group2
        .append('circle')
        .attr('id', 'cir')
        .attr('cx', posx * rad)
        .attr('cy', posy * rad)
        .attr('r', 2)
        .style('fill', 'steelblue')
        .style('opacity', 0.6);

 }
```

and it worked, it looks like this

[image]

then I tried to recreate the same composition but with full d3

```
var data = d3.range(2000).map(() => {
    return {
        cx: Math.cos(Math.random() * Math.PI * 2) * (Math.sqrt(~~(Math.random() * radius * radius))),
        cy: Math.sin(Math.random() * Math.PI * 2) * (Math.sqrt(~~(Math.random() * radius * radius))),
        r: 2
    };
});

var svg = d3
    .select('.container')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h);

var group = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(200,200)');

var c = group
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter( )
    .append('circle')
    .attrs(d => d)
    .style('fill', 'indianred')
    .style('opacity', 0.6);
```

and it looks like bounded to a rectangle instead of a circle

[image]

I don't know where I've done wrong, because the randomize function works properly, and I used the same mathematical formula, just in a different matter.

I want to recreate this because it's easier for me to animate each dot without the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to randomly generate `angle` and `rad` parameters and **then** use them. The current code you have generates its own parameters for `cx` and `cy` **separately**.

Do not forget that `Math.random()` return allways something different and therefore it can be dangerout to just copy lines with it. The working code can be

```
var data = d3.range(2000).map(() => {
    var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
    var rad = rad = Math.sqrt(~~(Math.random() * radius * radius));
    return {
        cx: Math.cos(angle) * (Math.sqrt(rad)),
        cy: Math.sin(angle) * (Math.sqrt(rad)),
        r: 2
    };
});
```